# what is the difference between inner and outer joins sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I tried to search in the google. But everyone is explaining about inner join and when comes to outer join they are including full outer join /left/right. I just want to know only the difference between inner join and outer join.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 0):

An inner join is where the columns match in both tables involved in the join, and will only return results where that condition is true. An outer join will return results even when there is no match, and will return nulls when the join condition is not met.

[Sql fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ef14/4)

Answer (score 0):

**Inner Join**

"Get all of the rows from both tables that match the join condition."

**Outer Join**

"Get all of the rows from the [left/right] table and join any rows that match the join condition from the other table."

**Full Outer Join**

"Get all of the rows from both tables and join any rows to each that match the join condition."

In the case of outer join if you say:

```
SELECT m.*, mo.*
FROM myTable m
LEFT OUTER JOIN myOtherTable mo ON m.Id = mo.myTableId
```

This will return all the rows from the left table (**myTable**) and any matching rows from **myOtherTable**.  Any rows from **myTable** without a match will have the values of mo.* set to **NULL**.

In the case of inner join if you say:

```
SELECT m.*, mo.*
FROM myTable m
INNER JOIN myOtherTable mo ON m.Id = mo.myTableId
```

You will only get the rows that match in both tables, so for instance if you have a **myTable** record with Id 15 and no **myOtherTable** records with the **myTableId** of 15 then no rows will be returned for **myTable** row with an Id 15.

There is another point to recognize that if there are multiple matches multiple rows will be returned.  So if you have 2 items in **myOtherTable** with a **myTableId** of 10 then the **myTable** row with Id of 10 will be duplicated, one row with the first record from **myOtherTable** joined, and one with the second record.